# Python oauth2 access to outlook emailbox

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

According to microsoft document from MSAL library, I can successfully get access token, the code is as follows:

```
import msal
import imaplib
import requests

def acquire_token():
    """
    Acquire token via MSAL
    """
    #authority_url = 'https://login.partner.microsoftonline.cn/******************'
    authority_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/*************************'
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        authority=authority_url,
        client_id='***********************',
        client_credential='***********************'
    )
    token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn/.default"])
    print(token)
    return token

def generate_auth_string(user, token):
    auth_string = f"user={user}\1auth=Bearer {token}\1\1"
    return auth_string

token = acquire_token()
# endpoint ="https://graph.chinacloudapi.cn/v1.0/me/mailFolders"
# http_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token["access_token"],
#                 'Accept': 'application/json',
#                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
# data = requests.get(endpoint, headers=http_headers, stream=False).json()
# print(data)
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("partner.outlook.cn", 993)
imap.authenticate("XOAUTH2", lambda x:generate_auth_string('##########',token["access_token"]))
imap.select('inbox')
```

If I can successfully get a token, does that mean the usage of MSAL part is not an issue, the issue is on authenticating part to emailbox?
Any help is really appreciated !

```
{'token_type': 'Bearer', 'expires_in': 3599, 'ext_expires_in': 3599, 'access_token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thomassun/Documents/imap.py", line 32, in <module>
    imap.authenticate("XOAUTH2", lambda x:generate_auth_string('clt.normal.user@handaten.com',token["access_token"]))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 444, in authenticate
    raise self.error(dat[-1].decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your authenticating and asking for a Token from the Graph API and then trying to use IMAP to access the mailbox which won't work (token will have the wrong audience). To use the Token you got for the Graph API then you need to use the Graph REST endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http eg there's a SDK for python and a tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad

You need to make sure you have assigned the Mail.Read application permissions in the Application registration.

or you could just use requests eg

```
def msgraph_request(resource, requestHeaders):
# Request
results = requests.get(resource, headers=requestHeaders).json()
return results

endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_email}/mailfolders/inbox/messages'
requestHeaders = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
result["access_token"],'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
queryResults = msgraph_request(endpoint ,requestHeaders)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, and I did your code, almost copy and past to run, unfortunately, it is the same problem, I'm not sure it is to do with Microsoft Azure in China, called 21vianet azure, and also I'm following the Python tutorial as well

Comment: I'd check the access token you getting back in jwt.io and make sure you getting the Mail.Read role. A common mistake is to give Delegate permissions instead of Application permissions